# Package held back message when upgrading ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am not able to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 because of the following message

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  gce-compute-image-packages google-compute-engine-oslogin
  python3-google-compute-engine
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

The upgrade command "do-release-upgrade" fail with message that I have unresolved packages.

How do I fix this issue so I can upgrade ubuntu.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Step 1: Review `apt cache policy` to determine **why** each is held back. If you want to keep those packages, then the reason is important.

Comment: You need to apply all upgrades **before** you can *release-upgrade*, given *bionic* or 18.04 is now EOSS, some packages are now more difficult to do upgrade, and thus removal of packages maybe required (*third party sources are free to drop support for EOSS or EOL releases*). The message shows you've either applied *hold* on those packages or something else on your *bionic* or 18.04 system given the description.

Comment: Consider fresh installing Ubuntu 22.04. It will be supported until 2027